# What is the inflorescence of Solanaceae family?

Tags: botany, flowers, morphology

> **Inflorescence of Solanaceae** : Solitary, Axillary or Cymose as in *solanum*

This was written in the textbook I was studying. Doesn't Solitary encompasses axillary inflorescence as well ?

Comment: Welcome Arun. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] particularly the [ask] section. You'll note that we deal with single focused questions, one per post. At present your question is very broad as the family you refer to has many different members (thousands of species) with different morphology. Could you [edit] to be much more specific and to show your prior research.

Comment: Sorry for causing inconvenience.  It is written in my textbook that inflorescence of Solanaceae family is solitary, axillary or cymose. That's the reason I asked the 2nd question because as far as I know, axillary are also a type of solitary inflorescence . Hope I will get some help.